# Python substring search not working as intended

Tags: python

I want the code to look for a string (IP Address) from another list and if there is a match do something:

```
for IP in map(str, container_data):
    IP=IP.strip()
    if IP in networkObjectHost:
        phantom.debug(IP)
        phantom.debug("is present in")
        phantom.debug(networkObjectHost)
    else:
        phantom.debug(IP)
        phantom.debug("is NOT present in")
        phantom.debug(networkObjectHost)
```

When I debug my code I can see the search is not working as desired as the IP Address 99.88.77.66 is not being matched. I have tried a couple things to try and work around but I think I am missing something fundamental here.

```
Fri Dec 20 2019 11:17:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): ['6.7.8.9']
Fri Dec 20 2019 11:17:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): is NOT present in
Fri Dec 20 2019 11:17:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): 
[
"network-object host 10.10.2.39",
"network-object host 99.88.77.66",
"network-object host 143.88.17.12",
"network-object host 48.48.56.76"
]
Fri Dec 20 2019 11:17:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): ['99.88.77.66']
Fri Dec 20 2019 11:17:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): is NOT present in
Fri Dec 20 2019 11:17:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): 
[
    "network-object host 10.10.2.39",
    "network-object host 99.88.77.66",
    "network-object host 143.88.17.12",
    "network-object host 48.48.56.76"
```

Implemented @Kuro's suggestion as follows, think I am still missing something as I don't see "IP Match Detected" message.

```
hosts = [elem.split()[-1] for elem in networkObjectHost] 

for IP in map(str, container_data):
    IP=IP.strip()
    phantom.debug("Debugging...") 
    phantom.debug(IP)
    phantom.debug(hosts)
    if IP in hosts:
        phantom.debug("IP Match Detected")
```

Output:

```
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): Debugging...
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): ['6.7.8.9']
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): 
[
    "10.10.2.39",
    "99.88.77.66",
    "143.88.17.12",
    "48.48.56.76"
]
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): Debugging...
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): 
['99.88.77.66']
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): 
[
    "10.10.2.39",
    "99.88.77.66",
    "143.88.17.12",
    "48.48.56.76"
]
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time): No actions were executed
Fri Dec 20 2019 12:48:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time):
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code or the output. It correctly recognizese that the IP is not in the list of IPs. What is your question?

Comment: I want my search for 99.88.77.66 to match on network-object host 99.88.77.66

Comment: Looks like you are comparing a list containing a string (looking at the debug print of "IP" with a list of strings.

The list of strings does not contain as an entry a list with a string value of your IP address, so it's not finding it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see is that `IP` is a list and `networkObjectHost` is a list of strings. You want to check whether the only element of `IP` (i.e `IP[0]` ) is present in any string of `networkObjectHost`. As the ip address (`99.88.77.66` in this case) is not equal to any of the string, the check fails. What you have to do is to split the `networkObjectHost` and fetch only the IP addresses from it. Like -

```
hosts = [elem.split()[-1] for elem in networkObjectHost]
```

The you can check on it.

```
if IP[0] in hosts:
   ....
```

**If the logging framework you are using, shows string as list then you don't need IP[0] and have to use IP**. I think that is the case as `IP.strip()` returns a string and not a list. In that case `IP[0]` will just be a single character (e.g in case of `6.7.8.9`, `IP[0]` will be only `6`)

Note that using `any(IP[0] in i for i in networkObjectHost)` will not work if your `IP[0]` is say `1.2.3.4` and `networkObjectHost` contains a string like `network-object host 51.2.3.4`. That is because `1.2.3.4` is present in that string but the ip address is not exactly same.

Comment: Tried this suggestion and both 6.7.8.9 and 99.88.77.66 show up as being present

Comment: @juanald_reagan, i have changed my answer. Please look into it

Comment: I updated but think I am still missing something, doesn't appear to find match - updated thread.

Comment: @juanald_reagan, can you check the type and length of say `hosts[1]`? also is this your actual code?

Comment: Also check if `hosts = [elem.split()[-1].strip() for elem in networkObjectHost]` works

Comment: Type is str and length is 11, tried second hosts=... with no success.

Comment: Yes actual code for Phantom platform where I have to substitute print statements with debug.

Comment: think I see the issue, when I debug IP length is reported as 15...believe the IP string includes the [ ' ' ] characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ip_in_list(IP, networkObjectHost)` instead of `IP in networkObjectHost` in your if statement:

```
def ip_in_list(IP, networkObjectHost):
    return any([IP[0] in i for i in networkObjectHost])
```

The issue with your current code is that Python is checking for the whole of `IP`  as an item in `networkObjectHost`.

Eg:

`IP = ['99.88.77.66']`

```
networkObjectHost = [
"network-object host 10.10.2.39",
"network-object host 99.88.77.66",
"network-object host 143.88.17.12",
"network-object host 48.48.56.76"
]
```

None of the items in `networkObjectHost` is `['99.88.77.66']`, so it returns `False`.
Instead, you want to check each of the items in `networkObjectHost` to see if it contains `IP`. However, `IP` is a list with a single item, so to check if the actual IP string is in `networkObjectHost`, we have to take the first item (index 0) and match that instead.